# TypeError: vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription is not a function

Tags: javascript, solidity

`

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat.config")
const { verify } = require("../helper-hardhat.config")

const FUND_AMOUNT = "100000000000000000" 

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subsciptionId

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
      
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId 
      
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
    const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
    const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
    const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]

    const args = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        entranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callbackGasLimit,
        interval,
    ]
    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("-------Verifying.... Please Wait !-------------")
        await verify(raffle.address, args)
    }
    log("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]`
```

Hello, I am learning solidity, and in the middle of writing a script for a contract. So, i am getting error `TypeError: vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubsctiption is not a function` with the code above. Now I had to make some adjustment as in another lesson we used
`const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")`
"deployments.get" to get the latest deployements. If I use:

`const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")`

the "getContract" piece is giving me this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContract')`

So I am stuck now, I had searched the discussions for "getContract" error, no luck, may be I am missing some "imports" as I cant use syntax `ethers.utils.parseEther` to input ETHER value as well. That thing is generating another error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')`. Please Help me out I am stuck and have no clue whats going on.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding hardhat-ethers using yarn this way:

```
    yarn add --dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers
```

and check your package.json file. this should fix the "calling from ethers" problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was facing the same issue after referring to the documentation i read about **getContractAt** function.

After deploying the mock contact. I get it's address. Here is the code

````
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config");


const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30");
module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts();
    const {deploy, log} = deployments;

    let VrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId;
    const chainId = network.config.chainId;

    
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const contractAddress = (await deployments.get('VRFCoordinatorV2Mock')).address;
        const vrfCoordinatorV2 = await ethers.getContractAt(
            'VRFCoordinatorV2Mock', 
            contractAddress
            );
        VrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2.address;

        // create the subscription
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2.createSubscription();
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;

        
        // Fund the contract with LINK
        await vrfCoordinatorV2.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT);
       
    } else {
        VrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinator"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    
    let entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"];
    let gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"];
    let callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"];
    let interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"];

    const args = [VrfCoordinatorV2Address, entranceFee, gasLane, subscriptionId, callbackGasLimit, interval]

    console.log(args)

    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,      
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    });

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: raffle.address,
            constructorArguments: args,
        })
    }
};


module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"];```
````